# Get Values to the Array Angular 2

Tags: arrays, class, angular, service

I have `Admin.ts` Class

```
export class AdminValues{

    nameAd:String;
    email_addr:String;
    passwrd:String;

    constructor(adminName:String,adminEmail:String,adminPassword:String){

        this.nameAd=adminName;
        this.email_addr=adminEmail;
        this.passwrd=adminPassword;
    }

}
```

I am completely new to Angular 2. I have created an admin form (AdminForm Component) to get input. I want create an Angular 2 service to add new admins to the Admin Type Array. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty broad questions, since there are an infinite number of ways to do this. [This article will give you a pretty good overview on getting started.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)

Most simply, you need to make a new file, with this content in it:

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminService {
  getArray() {
    return ['my array'];
  }
}
```

You will need to include this service in your app modules in the `providers` section, and import it into your `AdminForm` component. Something along the lines of `import { AdminService } from './AdminService';` should do the job.

You then should change your constructor to this:

```
constructor(private adminService: AdminService, adminName:String,adminEmail:String,adminPassword:String){

    this.nameAd=adminName;
    this.email_addr=adminEmail;
    this.passwrd=adminPassword;
}
```

Which will then give you access to your admin service and you can get your array.

```
myArray;

constructor(private adminService: AdminService, adminName:String,adminEmail:String,adminPassword:String){

    this.nameAd=adminName;
    this.email_addr=adminEmail;
    this.passwrd=adminPassword;
    this.myArray = adminService.getArray();
}
```

This answer should get you started, but if you need more in-depth information about services, the link at the top of this answer should have all the information you need to get going.

Comment: i already did what you told in first step .actually my adminValues Class is Model.in my service a created array adminDetails:AdminValues[] [  // save data ] .what i want is when i click my form submit button get that details and store in to this array.

Comment: You should post your code for your form template and your service then. Maybe edit your question to ask specifically what the problem is, since right now it's very broad.